# Clicking on a link in a table

Tags: webdriver

I have a table of four columns. The data in the first column is a name of a group in which I can click on to go to a new page to modify the group data.

I can get the text of that group name, but I am unable to click on it. I'm trying to go through each row and get the status of each group (located in column 4). If it's on hold, I want to modify the data of that group.

Here is my code: Why will it not click on the group name?

```
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='nameOfTable']/tbody/tr"));
for (WebElement rowElem : elems)
{
    List<WebElement> cells = rowElem.findElements(By.xpath("td"));

    if(cells.get(3).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Hold"))
    {
        System.out.println(cells.get(0).getText()); //
        cells.get(0).click; // This will not click on the link
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to say `cells.get(0).click();`.

I believe you are missing a couple of parentheses...

Comment: actually i do have cells.get(0).click();            I forgot to add that to my code above

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the html in question? I have some thoughts but I would need to see the html first.

Comment: code:   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%" id="feedsTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Version</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="editFeed.htm?feedId=1">TwoPack</a></td>
                <td>1.2</td>
                <td>Duo for Yuo</td>
                <td>Hold</td>
                <td>              
                </td>
            </tr>

Comment: In this case, the reason the click is not working is that your test is clicking on the <td> element instead of the <a> child element.  You will need to do something like cells.get(0).findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();

See: https://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/2e81ecd80acdc17b?pli=1

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are clicking the whole cell, not the link inside the cell. Try:

```
cells.get(0).findElements(By.TagName("a")).Click();
```

If the link is an <a> tag it will work, but you can use id, classname, etc... if it isn't.